# How to keep phone numbers out of the wrong fields. SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

SQL Server 2014. I need to write a query which produces a listing of accounts that have EITHER a phone number or an email address.

Phone numbers and emails are kept in 2 different tables. I'm using an inner join.

My issue is, when I run my query, phone numbers are inserted into columns they don't belong.

It displays like

```
Record 1     email@gmail.com              555-555-5555
Record 2     differentemail@yahoo.com     555-555-5555
```

Record 2 should not have a phone number associated. It was just an email address. But for some reason, record 1's phone number is duplicating over.

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    a.record_id, a.account_email, b.phone_number
FROM
    table1 AS a 
INNER JOIN
    Table2 AS b ON a.record_id = b.record_id 
                  OR a.record_id <> b.record_id 
                  AND a.account_email NOT IN ('NULL', '')
WHERE 
    (phone_number NOT IN (' ')
```

Comment: This is your `JOIN` is translated to `ON a.record_id = b.record_id OR (a.record_id <> b.record_id AND a.account_email NOT IN ('NULL',''))`, so of course it's all messed up.

Comment: Why do you use an inner join if you want accounts that only have an email adress

Comment: I want accounts that have Either or. So if there are emails but not an associated number I want that. And reverse as well. If there are phone numbers without associated emails I want those as well.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 1):

This is due because on your inner join clause you use `a.record_id <> b.record_id`

You should use a left join which will return nulls in the columns where there is no match.

```
Select Distinct a.record_id, a.account_email, b.phone_number
From table1 as a
LEFT JOIN Table2 as b ON a.record_id = b.record_id
```

Comment: There are still phone numbers duplicating with this into fields they shouldn't be?

Comment: You can always filter using `where` to remove empty phone numbers or empty emails or when both are null. Not sure exactly what your recordset is

Comment: I could only get it to show either all phone numbers or all emails. I just made it into two temp tables and then added them together for now. I want to figure out how to get them both together in one query.

Comment: Can you check this fiddle ? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e8280/1/0 and tell me what is different with yours? You have dupplicate phone numbers in your current tables or only when you do your query?

Answer (score 0):

a.record_id = b.record_id OR a.record_id <> b.record_id is contradicting itself in your join. In example below, a/b being whatever table phone_number is located in.

Try this:

```
SELECT a.record_id, a.account_email, b.phone_number
FROM table1 AS a 
INNER JOIN table2 as b ON
a.record_id = b.record_id
WHERE a/b.phone_number IS NOT NULL
AND a.account_email IS NOT NULL
```